# Decide whether the following is a smooth (1-dimensional manifold). If not, what are the trouble points? - Solution Verification

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Decide whether the following is a smooth (1-dimensional manifold)

$x^2 + y ^2 + z^2 - 1 = z^2 - xy = 0$

I'm asking this question because I want to know if I'm performing the analysis correctly with regards to determining whether a set is a manifold or not. I've only begun to learn about the concept so my understanding is still rudimentary.

Given this set of equations I perform the following analysis:

define $$F\left( \begin{array} \
x \\
y \\
z 
\end{array} \right) = \left[ \begin{array} \ 
x^2 + y ^2 + z^2 - 1 \\
z^{2} - xy 
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array} \
0 \\
0
\end{array} \right]$$

which yields the following derivative:

$$DF(\mathbf{x}) = \left[ \begin{array} \
2x & 2y & 2z \\
-y & -x & 2z \\
\end{array} \right]$$

In order for me to be able to obtain a 1 dimensional manifold it will be required that my derivative matrix is of $rank = 2$. So now I have to determine when that condition does not occur:

- if $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$ then the first expression of $F(\mathbf{x})$ would be undefined, so we can state that the point$(0,0,0$ does not occur in my subspace.
- if $x = y = 0$, then I would end up with $z = \pm 1$ in the first equation of $F(\mathbf{x})$ and $z = 0$ in the second equation. Again creating an impossible situation. So this scenario cannot occur.
- if $x = z = 0$ then $y = \pm 1$. This would give me a linearly dependent set of rows which would result in me only being able to write this curve as a 2-dimensional manifold. i.e as a function of $x,z$ for example: $ y =\phi(x,z)$ which also means $(x, \phi_{y}(x,z), z)$. (**I think, not sure about this conclusion**)
- with some fiddling around and row reduction I got the following matrix from $DF$:

$$DF(\mathbf{x}) = \left[ \begin{array} \
2x & 2y & 2z \\
-2x-y & -x-2y & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]$$

Which only yielded that if only one of $x,y,z$ are $0$ at one time I would get a matrix of $rank = 2$.

To conclude, trouble points would occur if$(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$, if $x = y = 0$, and if $x = z = 0$, besides these situations we would be able to obtain a 1 - dimensional manifold.

Is this the proper approach to thinking about such a scenario. Any feedback would be appreciated.